# Gnuplot sparse matrix display

Tags: gnuplot, sparse-matrix

I have a program that generates Gnuplot scripts to display the pattern of a Jacobian matrix.

For a dense matrix, I obtain that kind of code which does exactly what I want:

```
set terminal wxt persist
set title 'The Answer'
set palette defined(0 "white",1 "blue")
set grid front
set xrange [0:7]
set yrange [0:7] reverse
set size ratio -1
unset colorbox
plot '-' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):($3 == 0 ? 0 : 1) matrix with image notitle
1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
1.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00
1.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00
1.00 1.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
e
```

Since the rest of my code now handles sparse matrices, I have been trying to adapt the generation of Gnuplot scripts to achieve the same result with Gnuplot's binary data format. However, I have not succeeded without using an exterior file so far. How should I go about this?

Comment: If you're asking whether gnuplot can handle sparse matrices, AFAIK, the answer is No.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the information! Do you know if there is any clean workaround?